# Is it possible to add release burn down chart to Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: azure-devops, release, agile, burndowncharts

I would like to see a burndown chart after each sprint with my backlog of 100 pts of user stories. Is there plugin that I could integrate?

Answer (score 1):

VSTS does not support this for now. There are already two feature requests submitted for this on VSTS User Voice:

[Allow Burndown to use story points instead of hours](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2632616-allow-burndown-to-use-story-points-instead-of-hour)

[Add Story Point burndown to dashboard and reports](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/4473980-add-story-point-burndown-to-dashboard-and-reports)

According to the comments in the second one, Microsoft has started working on this feature.